# Service not registered: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech

Tags: android

I am testing my application for accessibility. If user switch off accessibility in mid between then application crashes with the reason Service not registered: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech. I have called setJavaScriptEnabled(false) in onDetachedFromWindow method but there was no use. Still error is coming.

I haven't use application context in webview because webview is getting initialized using xml.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@49df6be0
   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:940)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1983)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:541)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.disconnect(TextToSpeech.java:1575)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.run(TextToSpeech.java:732)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.run(TextToSpeech.java:727)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:1595)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:629)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runActionNoReconnect(TextToSpeech.java:615)
   at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.shutdown(TextToSpeech.java:727)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.AccessibilityInjector$TextToSpeechWrapper.shutdownInternal(AccessibilityInjector.java:462)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.AccessibilityInjector.removeAccessibilityApis(AccessibilityInjector.java:296)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.JellyBeanAccessibilityInjector.removeAccessibilityApis(JellyBeanAccessibilityInjector.java:97)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.AccessibilityInjector.addOrRemoveAccessibilityApisIfNecessary(AccessibilityInjector.java:162)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setInjectedAccessibility(ContentViewCore.java:2884)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setAccessibilityState(ContentViewCore.java:2875)
   at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$16.onChange(ContentViewCore.java:2839)
   at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: what is the exact functionality of accessibility service in your app

Comment: We haven;t done anything special for the accessibility. Just switched on accessibility and were testing. If we switch off accessiblity in between then application is crashing. All screens are using list view and some of them have cell items as webview and we are setting javascript enabled method. I have tried to call setJavascriptEnabled(false) in dispatchWindow method but of no use. Still getting this crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it has solved. I have to move all webview from the xml file and have added them dynamically and passing application context.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
```